# Preciso validar uma input mask do formulário de telefone do Ninja Forms

Tags: javascript, validação

Estou usando o Ninja Forms como meu plugin de formulário de contato. No momento uso um input mask para forçar a digitação de números. Mas preciso que a validação aconteça para o campo do telefone alcance 10 digitos completos ou 11 que são o caso dos celulares do Brasil. No momento a validação funciona para apenas uma quantidade de números. Alguém pode me ajudar descobrir como alterar esse código?

Comment: Se você postar seu código, ficará mais fácil ajudar. De preferência, um código que seja completo e verificável.

Comment: Que falta de sorte parceiro, meu site acabou perder contato com servidor. Mas o link está aqui http://www.rochacontabilidade.com.br

Answer (score -3):

Basta inserir a seguinte "MÁSCARA PERSONALIZADA" para ter o resultado esperado: (99) 9999-9999?9

[image: printo de onde inserir a mascara]